# dm77 barcodescanner Zbar camera Preview delay in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zbar

Hi I am using [this library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) for my android bar code reader and it is working fine with activities but it give some what delay in initiate(Not smooth like when it use in the Activities)when use with the fragment any solution for this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/actionbar_opacity"
        app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_enable_qr"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_layout_for_start_scan">



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is My Fragment & when application start I set this fragment to my main activity

```
public class ScannerFragment extends Fragment implements ZBarScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private ZBarScannerView mScannerView;
    private FrameLayout contentFrame;
    RelativeLayout enableQR;
    private static final int ZBAR_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1;

    public static ScannerFragment newInstance() {
        return new ScannerFragment();
    }


    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_full_scanner, container, false);
            contentFrame = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
            enableQR = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_enable_qr);


            enableQR.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                            launchActivity();
                            break;
                        }
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                            releaseCamera();
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.e(TAG, "onCreateView: " + e.toString());
        }

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, ZBAR_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            setUpQrScanner();
        }
    }

    public void setUpQrScanner() {
        mScannerView = new ZBarScannerView(getActivity());
        mScannerView.setFormats(BarcodeFormat.ALL_FORMATS);
        contentFrame.addView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(ScannerFragment.this);
        mScannerView.startCamera(-1);
        mScannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
    }

    public void releaseCamera() {
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
        contentFrame.removeView(mScannerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
        try {
            scannerSoundAndVibration();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Result" + rawResult.getContents()+" TYPE: "+rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void scannerSoundAndVibration() {
        /**
         * scanner sound alert time in millisecond
         */
        final ToneGenerator tg = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 200);
        tg.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_KEYPAD_VOLUME_KEY_LITE);

        /**
         * scanner vibration alert time in millisecond
         */
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        v.vibrate(250);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,  String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ZBAR_CAMERA_PERMISSION:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  setUpQrScanner();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please grant camera permission to use the QR Scanner", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: delay in activity or fragments ?

Comment: delay when it use with Fragment

Comment: @Dulaga, zbar scanner is not light weight view, so in fragment it may takes more time compare to activity screen. so to avoid this you may display toast for displaying loading or please wait.

Comment: @Nirav, Any solution or improvement for this because I used this with Tabhost Fragment so I cant replace this with Activity :(

Comment: you can show toast as soon as screen appears like "Preparing Scan" or something else just for user responsive. or you may search for other solution that may i dont know.